# Opening the external link through showModalDialog()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Is there any way to open an external link through showModalDialog function
I mean to say I want to open "www.google.com" in the opened pop-up through showModalDialog().

Please reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8Lqp/2/)

```
<script language="javascript">
   window.showModalDialog("http://stackoverflow.com/users/1310467/hatsoft");​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open external link with showModalDialog function as described in previous post,just remember that if your external link is cross domain showModalDialog wont return any result value.